# Android SQLite increments an AutoIncrement Integer Primary Key upon read using SqliteDatabase.query()

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having a weird bug with a module in my program, where my data's integer primary keys in my Sqlite database table are incremented upon reading from the database through .query(). I've also initiated my SqliteDatabase as DatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase() only, and I'm expecting that my primary keys will only increment during insertion (.insert()).

The UI is as basic as a RecyclerView list, let's call this ListA, where when an item was clicked, it will show a custom dialog box that contains another list where multiple selection is allowed, through checkboxes, and an extra checkbox that has an additional EditText that accepts a String; let's call this ListB. This custom dialog box that holds ListB has two buttons, one being the Cancel, and the other one Saves and "Remembers" the items chosen by the user, as this ListB can still accessed again after the custom dialog box has been closed by Cancel.

Basically I have two methods (with some separate methods to segregate functions) triggered by clicks. Pardon my method names as I've made some iterations of solution to solve this problem.

The method below is triggered when an item in the ListA was clicked.

```
private void createRemarksObjects2(JSONArray remarks) {
    if (lstRemarks != null) {
        lstRemarks.clear();

        String remarksKey = "remark";
        DataManager    dm = DataManager.getInstance(mContext);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dm.getReadableDatabase();

        logTableValues(db.query(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null));

        // loop on the JSONArray
        for (int i = 0; i < remarks.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject remark = remarks.getJSONObject(i);

                if (remark.getString(remarksKey).equals(ComponentRemark.OTHERS_KEY)) {
                    String[] columns   = { Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NOTE };
                    String whereClause = String.format("%s = ? AND %s = ?", Schema.TableFindingRemarks.FINDING_ID, Schema.TableFindingRemarks.REMARK_NAME);
                    String[] whereArgs = {String.valueOf(mComponentId), remark.getString(remarksKey)};

                    Cursor cursor2 = db.query(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NAME, columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
                    cursor2.moveToFirst();

                    ComponentRemark otherRemark;
                    if (cursor2.getCount() > 0) {
                        otherRemark = new ComponentRemark(i, ComponentRemark.OTHERS_REMARK, ComponentRemark.OTHERS_KEY, cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NOTE)), cursor2.getCount() > 0);
                    } else {
                        otherRemark = new ComponentRemark(i, ComponentRemark.OTHERS_REMARK, ComponentRemark.OTHERS_KEY, "", false);
                    }

                    lstRemarks.add(otherRemark);
                    cursor2.close();
                } else {
                    String[] columns   = { Schema.TableFindingRemarks.ID };
                    String whereClause = String.format("%s = ? AND %s = ?", Schema.TableFindingRemarks.FINDING_ID, Schema.TableFindingRemarks.REMARK_NAME);
                    String[] whereArgs = {String.valueOf(mComponentId), remark.getString(remarksKey)};

                    Cursor cursor1 = db.query(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NAME, columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
                    cursor1.moveToFirst();

                    ComponentRemark componentRemark = new ComponentRemark(i, remark.getString(remarksKey), cursor1.getCount() > 0);

                    lstRemarks.add(componentRemark);
                    cursor1.close();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "JSON exception error! Please contact the administrator", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        db.close();
    } else {
        lstRemarks = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

This method accepts a JSONArray that contains the items to be presented, and is checking the database whether that particular item is currently saved in the sqlite database table, and when it is, that item will then be marked at checked.

The next method(s) is/are triggered when the user clicks the Save/Update button in the custom dialog box.

```
 private void updateSelectedRemarks2() {
    DataManager    dm = DataManager.getInstance(mContext);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dm.getWritableDatabase();
    List<ContentValues> lstRows = getCheckedRemarks(db);

    if (lstRows == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please input notes for 'others' remark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (lstRows.size() > 0) {
            for (ContentValues values : lstRows) {
                String whereClause = String.format("%s = ? AND %s = ?", Schema.TableFindingRemarks.FINDING_ID, Schema.TableFindingRemarks.REMARK_NAME);
                String[] whereArgs = { String.valueOf(mComponentId), values.getAsString(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.REMARK_NAME) };
                String[] columns = { String.valueOf(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.ID) };
                Cursor cursor = db.query(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NAME, columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);

                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    String updateWhere = String.format("%s = ?", Schema.TableFindingRemarks.ID);
                    String[] updateWhereArgs = { String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.ID))) };
                    db.update(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NAME, values, updateWhere, updateWhereArgs);
                } else {
                    db.insert(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NAME, null, values);
                }

                cursor.close();
                broadcastToListeners();
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    logTableValues(db.query(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null));
    db.close();
}

private List<ContentValues> getCheckedRemarks(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    List<ContentValues> lstRows = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ComponentRemark remark : lstRemarks) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.clear();

        if (remark.isChecked()) {
            if (remark.getRemarkType() == ComponentRemark.NORMAL_REMARK) {
                values.put(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.FINDING_ID,  mComponentId);
                values.put(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.REMARK_NAME, remark.getLabel());
            } else {
                if (remark.getRemarkType() == ComponentRemark.OTHERS_REMARK) {
                    if (remark.getNote().equals("") || remark.getNote() == null) {
                        return null;
                    } else {
                        values.put(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.FINDING_ID,  mComponentId);
                        values.put(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.REMARK_NAME, remark.getLabel());
                        values.put(Schema.TableFindingRemarks.NOTE, remark.getNote());
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "There's something wrong with the data. Please contact the administrator", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            lstRows.add(values);
        }

    }

    return lstRows;
}
```

The first method is what's triggered, and also handles the final saving/updating of the checked/selected items from ListB. When the item already exists in the database, the method will update the item instead of inserting another one. The second method, getCheckedRemarks() (disregard the parameter), checks if the item was checked through a model class that corresponds to the row of data in the database, and this ComponentRemark.isChecked() method that returns a boolean, is being updated by checking/unchecking items in ListB (which works fine BTW).

The last item on ListB is always labelled as "Others", and accepts a String from the EditText beside it. When this String is empty, the getCheckedRemarks() returns a null instead as my validation check in the first method, updateSelectedRemarks2().

Now, the problem is, when I click an item in ListA, and the ListB of this ListA already has selected items before, the items will be checked, but the String on the EditText for the "Others" item does not appear, not because of UI error, but because it becomes NULL in the database.

Upon saving the selected items of ListB, items in the database are intact, but when I re-click that particular item in ListA, the ID's of the data are all incremented by 1, the "Note" column of the "Others" item becomes NULL.

I've also made a method that shows all rows of data in table, named logTableValues().

```
private void logTableValues(Cursor cursor) {
    String TAG = "note-track";
    String headers = "";
    String rows = "";

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        for (String colname : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
            headers += "| " + colname;
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                rows += "| " + cursor.getColumnName(i) + "=" + cursor.getString(i);
            }
            rows += "\n";
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "nothing can be seen");
    }

    String log = "Table Schema:\n" + headers + "\n" + rows;
    Log.i(TAG, log);
    cursor.close();
}
```

This log is after I have saved my selection:

```
    09-30 14:18:51.685 578-578/com.victoriacourt.autopilot I/note-track: Table Schema:
                                                                     | id| finding_id| name| note
                                                                     | id=130| finding_id=1| name=PAINT FADED| note=
                                                                     | id=131| finding_id=1| name=BUSTED LIGHT| note=
                                                                     | id=132| finding_id=1| name=OTHERS| note=sample
```

These are the logs that appear whenever I re-open the custom dialog box from ListA

```
    09-30 14:20:36.566 578-578/com.victoriacourt.autopilot I/note-track: Table Schema:
                                                                     | id| finding_id| name| note
                                                                     | id=133| finding_id=1| name=PAINT FADED| note=
                                                                     | id=134| finding_id=1| name=BUSTED LIGHT| note=
                                                                     | id=135| finding_id=1| name=OTHERS| note=
09-30 14:20:37.706 578-578/com.victoriacourt.autopilot I/note-track: Table Schema:
                                                                     | id| finding_id| name| note
                                                                     | id=133| finding_id=1| name=PAINT FADED| note=
                                                                     | id=134| finding_id=1| name=BUSTED LIGHT| note=
                                                                     | id=135| finding_id=1| name=OTHERS| note=
09-30 14:20:42.686 578-578/com.victoriacourt.autopilot I/note-track: Table Schema:
                                                                     | id| finding_id| name| note
                                                                     | id=136| finding_id=1| name=PAINT FADED| note=
                                                                     | id=137| finding_id=1| name=BUSTED LIGHT| note=
                                                                     | id=138| finding_id=1| name=OTHERS| note=
```

I'm using this library/file from this GitHub project:
https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android
and when I'm viewing by database through the activity created by these codes, the ID's are also incremented once more, but it multiple times does not increment the ID's any more.

Comment: I don't see any of the code which calls logging functions.

Comment: Ah okay sorry, I thought it wouldn't be relevant. I'll edit my question, but in the mean time, the function itself, logTableValues(), is being called at the start of createRemarksObjects2() and at the end of updateSelectedRemarks2()

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have edited my question and included the codes for the logTableValues() method, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I doubt that calling `query()` changes data in your tables. Otherwise you would see many note increments, one for the logging and one for the production code. (You can test this with two of the exact see calls to `logTableValues()` in a row. I suggest you add more logging to track down exactly where and when the data is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on calling my logger method twice. I've made each call of the method twice, and it logs the same with one another. Looks like there are things happening in between although there's not much of them that do. I've been logging the values in the database for 2 days now and this is the closest I've been. Can you suggest how I can monitor my database aside from using the Android util logs? i.e. something that functions like the MySql Workbench or a PHPMyAdmin dashboard. I've also edited my answer as I forgot to mention something but I don't think it affects my problem much

Comment: If you are comfortable with the command line, you can use `adb shell` and `sqlite3` and then give any SQL queries you wish.